How do I get the following graph to not color in code above both call & put value lines?
How do I get the following graph to not color in code above both call & put value lines as can be seen around the x=20 mark? FYI file runs with streamlit.
Here is current code for graph.
st.header("Theoretical Value of Call and Put Options")

# Range of Spot Prices and Strike Prices
spot_prices2 = np.arange(spot_price_range2[0], spot_price_range2[1] + 1, 1)

# Calculate the option values
call_values = np.maximum(spot_prices2 - strike_price2, 0) - option_price
put_values = np.maximum(strike_price2 - spot_prices2, 0) - option_price

# Plot the graphs
fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 5))
ax2.plot(spot_prices2, call_values, label='Call Option Value', color='green')
ax2.plot(spot_prices2, put_values, label='Put Option Value', color='red')

# Fill areas for Call Option profit (above 0)
ax2.fill_between(spot_prices2, 0, call_values,
                 where=(call_values > 0) & (put_values <= 0),
                 color='green', alpha=0.3, label='Call Profit Area')

# Fill areas for Call Option loss (below 0)
ax2.fill_between(spot_prices2, call_values, 0,
                 where=(call_values < 0) & (put_values <= 0),
                 color='red', alpha=0.3, label='Call Loss Area')

# Fill areas for Put Option profit (above 0)
ax2.fill_between(spot_prices2, 0, put_values,
                 where=(put_values > 0) & (call_values <= 0),
                 color='green', alpha=0.3, label='Put Profit Area')

# Fill areas for Put Option loss (below 0)
ax2.fill_between(spot_prices2, put_values, 0,
                 where=(put_values < 0) & (call_values <= 0),
                 color='red', alpha=0.3, label='Put Loss Area')

# Adjust Y-axis limits
ax2.set_ylim(pnl2[0], pnl2[1])

# Draw a horizontal line at zero for reference
ax2.axhline(0, color='black', linewidth=1)

# Label the axes and set the title
ax2.set_xlabel('Spot Price of Underlying (USD)')
ax2.set_ylabel('Profit and Loss')
ax2.set_title('Theoretical Value of Call and Put Options')

# Add a legend
ax2.legend()

# Render the plot in Streamlit
st.pyplot(fig2)

enter image description here
Besides the legend which has some issues, we can observe that, around the x=20 mark, an area above both call & put option values lines is colored in. It shouldn't, hence the reason for my post.

Welcome to SO. Would you be able to add some sample data to make it easier for us to help you? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
